# Terraform to customize the VM provisioned in the Vsphere Hypervisor

Tags: windows, powershell, terraform, customization, vsphere

I am able to provision the VM using Vsphere provider and join to the Domain, but when i tried to copy a file or execute powershell commands to the provisioned server, it is failing.
in my template i have enabled count

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {

  count = var.vm_count
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
....
}
```

which will allow to create multiple vm's based on input validation

in the windows customization

```
   customize {
      windows_options {
        computer_name = "${var.host_prefix}${count.index + 1}"
        join_domain           = "domainname"
        domain_admin_user     = "username"
        domain_admin_password = "password"
        time_zone             = "004"
      }
```

### enabled DHCP for

```
  network_interface {

      }
```

with the above code i am able to create vm and add them to domain controller successfully.

Post that, i would like to enable iis in each vm,  I have written the below code

```
  resource "null_resource" "example_provisioner" {


      connection {
        host =  "${var.host_prefix}${count.index + 1}"
        type  = "winrm"
        user  = "username"
        password = "password"
        insecure = false
        agent = true
      }



  // copy our example script to the server
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "e://iis.ps1"
    destination = "c://iis.ps1"
  }


  // change permissions to executable and pipe its output into a new file
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "powershell.exe c://iis.ps1",
       ]
  }
  }
```

below is the error of the null provision when i use hostname = `"${var.host_prefix}${count.index + 1}".`
PS E:\terraform\vmware> terraform plan
var.host_prefix
  Enter a value: abchostname

var.vm_count
  Enter a value: 1

Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context

on base.tf line 140, in resource `"null_resource" "example_provisioner":`

```
 140:     host = "${var.host_prefix}${count.index + 1}"
```

The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.

can somebody help me to run the powershell commands on newly provisioned vm's using vpshere resource with count parameters.

Comment: You forgot to also put the `count = var.vm_count` in your `null_resource`. That should move you forward.

Comment: this is throwing an error, it is not expected under null resource